# VC++ Multiple Project Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am very new to C++ and I am attempting to setup multiple projects in the same solution in VS2013. Currently I have stepped back to a simpler example project to try to figure out my error.

Project 1:
Main.cpp

```
 #include "Test.h"
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main() 
 {
     cout << _MOVEMENTSPEED();
     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Project 2
Test.h

```
 #ifndef TEST_H
 #define TEST_H

 int _MOVEMENTSPEED();

 #endif
```

Test.cpp

```
 #include "Test.h"

 int _MOVEMENTSPEED() 
 {
     return 10;
 }
```

Whenever I attempt to build this I get the error "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl _MOVEMENTSPEED(void)" (?_MOVEMENTSPEED@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\Max\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Project2\Main.obj" and "Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\max\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Project1\Debug\Internal".

**UPDATE**
I tested this same code but within one project file in visual studio and it worked fine.

Comment: Do you notice leading underscore in `Test.cpp::_MOVEMENTSPEED()` ?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed that and attempted another build but no change in the errors.

Comment: Your problem is failing to properly **export** your function as an exposed function in your DLL. Search for "exporting a function from a DLL" and you'll get *hundreds* of hits.

Comment: Are Test.h and Main.cpp in same directory? Probably not - so you need to update the `#include "Test.h"` in Main.cpp with correct path. Ex: `#include "../Project2/Test.h"`. Alternatively you can add the include directory into Project 1's properties.

Comment: I already added that as a Additional Include Directory in the projects properties.

Comment: @MaxYoung What is your "Project2" type (executable, static lib, dynamic lib)? Are you linking Project1 to Project2?

Comment: In Project1's Properties, under linker's options add Additional Dependency as Test.obj (with path). Better way would be to create static library from Project2 and add Project2 as Reference in Project1.

Comment: @Drop Project2 is a .dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create multiple projects you should do the following:

Make sure the following:

1. Include the .h file properly from other project(Generally every project has its own directory), so you need to include the file like below:
   **#include "..\Test\Test.h"**
2. Export the function / class by using **_*declspec(dllexport)*** and **_declspec(dllimport)**
3. Include the .lib file properly in the project settings of Link tab.
4. Set the project dependencies correctly.

The below links should help you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815650

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx